# EUCA 4.4.5 Breaking Storage

Tags: eucalyptus

I have my SC/CC and CLC on two seperate RHEL 7 hosts.  I'm using **overlay** storage mode.  If I hard reboot the SC/CC and even sometimes if I initiate an orderly `reboot now` I keep breaking storage and end up with the following in `/var/log/eucalyptus/cloud-error.log` on my SC.

`ERROR [BindingCache:main] [com.eucalyptus.binding.BindingCache$BindingFileSearch$DeleteRecursively.apply(BindingCache.java):195] Unable to delete file: /var/run/eucalyptus/classcache`

The `/var/log/eucalyptus/cloud-output.log` shows the SC waiting for contact from the CLC.
`INFO | Waiting for system view with database...`

The `euctl` command shows a valid block storage manager value `zone-1.storage.blockstoragemanager = overlay`

I've tried restarting EUCA services on the CLC after my SC is back up with no luck.  I seem to be able to fix it by de-registering and re-registering the SC and re-issuing the euctl command for overlay storage.  Am I doing something wrong by unceremoniously shutting down my SC and is there a more elegant way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple network interfaces you should set the bind address in eucalyptus.conf on hosts running a eucalyptus-cloud service (e.g. CLC, SC)

```
CLOUD_OPTS="--bind-addr=192.168.123.123"
```

You should also verify that multicast works in your environment as this is used for communication between hosts.

Comment: Thanks, Steve.  I do have multiple interfaces and this did the trick.